# PowerShell classes and .NET events

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script with a small WPF GUI. My code is organzized in a class from which a singleton is created. I have read that $this inside an event handler script block points to the event sender and not to my containing class instance. How can I access my class instance from the event handler?

Ex.

```
class MyClass {

    $form  #Reference to the WPF form


    [void] StartAction([object] $sender, [System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs] $e) {
        
        ...
    }


    [void] SetupEventHandlers() {

        $this.form.FindName("BtnStartAction").add_Click({ 
            param($sender, $e) 
            # !!!! Does not work, $this is not my class instance but the event sender !!!!
            $this.StartAction($sender, $e) 
        })

    }


    [void] Run() {

        $this.InitWpf() #Initializes the form from a XAML file.

        $this.SetupEventHandlers()

        ...
    }
}


$instance = [MyClass]::new()
$instance.Run()
```

Comment: Can you try creating an instance inside `SetupEventHandlers` like `$instance=$this` and use `$instance` inside the handler(`add_Click`)?

Comment: the `$sender` is your class in `add_click`. `StartAction` is not an event handler, it is just a method of your class. Modify `StartAction` signature and call the method `([MyClass]$sender).StartAction()` in the event handler by casting `$sender`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Indeed, the **[automatic `$this` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#this) in a *script block* acting as a *.NET event handler* refers to the *event sender***.
- If an **event-handler script block is set up *from inside a method of a [PowerShell custom `class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)***, the **event-sender definition of `$this` *shadows* the usual definition** in a class method (referring to the class instance at hand).

There are two **workarounds**, both **relying on PowerShell's *dynamic scoping***, which allows descendant scopes to see variables from ancestral scopes.

- Use **[`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) `-Scope 1`** to **reference the *parent* scope's `$this` value** (event-handler script blocks run in a *child scope* of the caller).

```bash
    [void] SetupEventHandlers() {

        $this.form.FindName("BtnStartAction").add_Click({ 
            param($sender, $e) 
            # Get the value of $this from the parent scope.
            (Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Scope 1 this).StartAction($sender, $e) 
        })

    }
```

- Taking more direct advantage of dynamic scoping, you can go with [Abdul Niyas P M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699447/abdul-niyas-p-m)'s suggestion, namely to **define a *helper variable in the caller's scope* that references the custom-class instance *under a different name***, which you can reference in - potentially multiple - event-handler script blocks set up from the same method:

  - Note that a call to [`.GetNewClosure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure) is required on the script block, so as to make the helper variable available inside the script block.<sup>Tip of the hat to [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15101500/sven).</sup>

```bash
    [void] SetupEventHandlers() {

        # Set up a helper variable that points to $this
        # under a different name.
        $thisClassInstance = $this

        # Note the .GetNewClosure() call.
        $this.form.FindName("BtnStartAction").add_Click({ 
            param($sender, $e) 
            # Reference the helper variable.             
            $thisClassInstance.StartAction($sender, $e) 
        }.GetNewClosure())

    }
```

Also note that, **as of PowerShell 7.2, you cannot directly use custom-class *methods* as event handlers** - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64236498/45375) shows workarounds, which also require solving the `$this` shadowing problem.

---

**Self-contained sample code**:

- **Important**: Before running the code below, ensure that you have run the following in your session:

  ```bash
  # Load WPF assemblies.
  Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework
  ```
- Unfortunately, placing this call *inside* a script that contains the code below does *not* work, because `class` definitions are processed at *parse time*, i.e., *before* the `Add-Type` command runs, whereas all .NET types referenced by a class must already be
  loaded - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813639/45375).

  - While `using assembly` statements in lieu of `Add-Type` calls may *some day* be a solution (they too are processed at parse time), their types aren't currently discovered until runtime, leading to the same problem - see [GitHub issue #3641](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3641#issuecomment-297151112); as a secondary problem, well-known assemblies cannot currently be referenced by file *name* only; e.g., `using assembly PresentationCore.dll` does *not* work, unlike `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore` - see [GitHub issue #11856](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11856)

```bash
# IMPORTANT: 
#  Be sure that you've run the following to load the WPF assemblies
#  BEFORE calling this script:
#    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework

class MyClass {

  $form  #Reference to the WPF form

  [void] InitWpf() {
    [xml] $xaml=@"
    <Window
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="BtnStartAction" Content="StartAction" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" IsDefault="True" Height="22" Margin="170,0,0,0" />        
            <TextBox x:Name="Log" Height="400" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Padding="4" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,40,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
"@    
    $this.form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml))
  }

  [void] StartAction([object] $sender, [System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs] $e) {
      
      $tb = $this.form.FindName("Log")
      $tb.Text += $e | Out-String
  }


  [void] SetupEventHandlers() {

      $btn = $this.form.FindName("BtnStartAction")

      # -- Solution with Get-Variable
      $btn.add_Click({ 
          param($sender, $e) 
          (Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Scope 1 this).StartAction($sender, $e) 
      }.GetNewClosure())

      # -- Solution with helper variable.
      # Note the need for .GetNewClosure()
      # Helper variable that points to $this under a different name.
      $thisClassInstance = $this
      $btn.add_Click({ 
          param($sender, $e) 

          $thisClassInstance.StartAction($sender, $e)
      }.GetNewClosure())

  }

  [void] Run() {
      $this.InitWpf() #Initializes the form from a XAML file.
      $this.SetupEventHandlers()
      $this.form.ShowDialog()
  }
}


$instance = [MyClass]::new()
$instance.Run()
```

The above demonstrates both workarounds: when you press the `StartAction` button, both event handlers should add the event-arguments object they've each received to the text box, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, @Sven. While the `Get-Variable` workaround worked fine, the helper-variable workaround indeed requires `.GetNewClosure()` - please see my update, which includes self-contained sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
class MyClass {

    $form  #Reference to the WPF form


    [void] StartAction([System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs] $e) {
        #$this ...
    }


    [void] SetupEventHandlers() {

        $this.form.FindName("BtnStartAction").add_Click({ 
            param($sender, $e) 
            ([MyClass]$sender).StartAction($e)
        })

    }


    [void] Run() {
        $this.InitWpf()
        $this.SetupEventHandlers()
    }
}


$instance = [MyClass]::new()
$instance.Run()
```

Edit 1:
Could you try creating a delegate referring to a dedicated method of the class like this?

```
class MyClass {

    $form  #Reference to the WPF form
    
    [void] StartAction() {
        #$this ...
    }


    [void] SetupEventHandlers() {
        $handler = [System.EventHandler]::CreateDelegate([System.EventHandler], $this, "Handler")
    
        $this.form.FindName("BtnStartAction").add_Click($handler)

    }

    [void] Handler ([System.Object]$sender, [System.EventArgs]$e) {
        $this.StartAction()
    }

    [void] Run() {
        $this.InitWpf()
        $this.SetupEventHandlers()
    }
}


$instance = [MyClass]::new()
$instance.Run()
```

Comment: Note that the `$sender` in the event-handler script block is the _event sender, i.e. the WPF button control, not the custom-class instance at hand. Unfortunately, `$this` _also_ refers to the event sender, and it is this shadowing of `$this` that makes it challenging to refer to the custom-class instance at hand.

Comment: I confirm that this does not work for me. Debugging shows: $sender.Name is BtnStartAction, so it's the button and not the custom-class instance and trying to cast it to MyClass fails.